# SQL available instruments between selected dates

Tags: c#, sql

I have an instrument booking system and I want to find instruments that are available.

I want to select all instrument information when the Instrument is not in the Rental table between the selected dates.

I am using the following code but it is not returning any results (there should be 5 available)

```
public List<Instrument> availableInstruments(DateTime startDate, DateTime returnDate)
    {
        //string startDate1 = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
        //string returnDate1 = returnDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
       List<Instrument> availableInstruments = new List<Instrument>();
       db.Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startDate1", startDate));
       db.Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@returnDate1", returnDate));
       db.Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM InstrumentTBL WHERE InstrumentID NOT IN (SELECT InstrumentTBL.InstrumentID FROM InstrumentTBL IT JOIN RentalTBL DT ON IT.InstrumentID = DT.InstrumentID Where(DT.DateOut <= @startDate1  AND DT.ReturnDate >= @returnDate1) OR (DT.DateOut < @returnDate1 AND DT.ReturnDate >= @returnDate1) OR (@startDate1 <= DT.DateOut AND @returnDate1 >= DT.DateOut))";
       db.Rdr = db.Cmd.ExecuteReader();
       while (db.Rdr.Read())
       {
           availableInstruments.Add(getInstrumentFromReader(db.Rdr)); // store into list
       }
        db.Rdr.Close();
        return availableInstruments;
    }
```

I am using 2 tables an instrument table and a rental table, the dateout and returndate are in the rental table.

I got the code from another thread and I tried to adopt it but with little success.

Please any help at all is welcomed.

Comment: table structure + example data + expected output plz. Don't make us guess

Comment: I tried to add an image but Im not allowed for some reason. Sorry. Thank you for your response I will try to edit the post with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your select

```
SELECT * FROM InstrumentTBL 
WHERE InstrumentID NOT 
IN (SELECT DT.InstrumentID 
    FROM RentalTBL DT 
    Where(DT.DateOut >= @startDate1  AND DT.ReturnDate <= @returnDate1))
```

Comment: Thank you I used your response and added some of mine to it and it works (will test more extensively later) I cant add the final code because of the @ symbols sorry. Thank you.